# Angular, data in one controller filter to this data in other

Tags: angularjs, filter

At start i want to say im new in angular. Lets say my page look like this:

index.html:

```
<body ng-app="application">
 <div class="container">
   <div class="row">

   <div class="col-sm-3 sideBar" ng-controller="NavController">
     <input ng-model"search">
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-9 content" ng-controller="ContentController">
     <div ng-repeat="meet in meets | filter:search">
       {{ meet.someData }}
     </div>
   </div>

   </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

And how can i make that input in NavController could filter data from ContentController? I want to do this in two controllers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want to do this in two controllers, but it will be considerably more difficult. The Search functionality acts on the data in the content controller. I am guessing that your layout is driving your controller design.

There are numerous posts here that discuss techniques for this. This one: [Share data between AngularJS controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/angular-share-data-between-controllers) is well-regarded.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can just do that in a single controller.

```js
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = [{
    "id":1
  },{
    "id":2
  },{
    "id":3
  }]

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="angularjs-starter">
  
  <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Custom Plunker</title>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.1.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl"><input ng-model='find' />
    <div ng-repeat="x in name | filter : find">
      {{x.id}}
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

For understanding, i used numbers as data. :) Hope it helps you

Comment: I know its easier to do this in one controller but as @MikeFeltman guessed my layout didnt allow me to do this in one controller

Comment: I think a concern that can come up is having one controller doing too much. I don't know about you, but I'm not keen on a 10,000 line long controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a parent controller over the other two controllers. If you use the `controllerAs` method you can have controllers inside each other, see [Angular Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#controllers) for helpful information about controllers and controllerAs.

You could write it like that and bind the search model to the ParentController.

**Edit:** I added another solution that I think is better

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ParentController', function() {
  this.search = 'p'; //set default just for fun
});

app.controller('NavController', function() {
  //nav stuff

});

app.controller('ContentController', function() {
  this.meets = [{
    data: 'hi'
  }, {
    data: 'potato'
  }, {
    data: 'help me'
  }, {
    data: 'pie'
  }];

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div class="container" ng-controller="ParentController as parentVm">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-sm-3 sideBar" ng-controller="NavController as navVm">
        <input ng-model="parentVm.search">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9 content" ng-controller="ContentController as contentVm">
        <div ng-repeat="meet in contentVm.meets | filter:parentVm.search">
          {{ meet.data }}
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I stepped away from this for a bit and thought of another idea that doesn't involve using another controller. Here you are using a factory instead to communicate between the controllers. You have to share an object so that when you change the `search.term` in the input it will change for every reference.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.factory('Searcher', function() {
  return {
    search: {
      term: 'p'
    }
  };
});

app.controller('NavController', function(Searcher) {
  //nav stuff
  this.search = Searcher.search;

});

app.controller('ContentController', function(Searcher) {
  this.search = Searcher.search;
  this.meets = [{
    data: 'hi'
  }, {
    data: 'potato'
  }, {
    data: 'help me'
  }, {
    data: 'pie'
  }];

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-sm-3 sideBar" ng-controller="NavController as navVm">
        <input ng-model="navVm.search.term">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9 content" ng-controller="ContentController as contentVm">
        <div ng-repeat="meet in contentVm.meets | filter:contentVm.search.term">
          {{ meet.data }}
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```